# MYSQL - Warning: #1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release

Tags: mysql, window-functions, row-number

Warning: #1287 Setting user variables within expressions is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Consider alternatives: 'SET variable=expression, ...', or 'SELECT expression(s) INTO variables(s)'.

This is what MySQL 8.0.21 spits out. The code works... But I need it to work in future versions too.... So my question is what is the correct approach to this warning?

I need a variable to be set to some number (which I will get via ID of a row). And I need it to be incremented by 1 with every SET statement.

How should I change this code so the warning would go away?

```
SET @fromorder = (SELECT `order` FROM forms WHERE id=5);
/* SET @fromorder = 4;  - so this is the same in the example below */
UPDATE forms SET `order` = @fromorder := @fromorder + 1 WHERE `order` > -1 and `order` <= 4 ORDER BY `order` ASC;
SET @fromorder = null;
```

The problem as I understand underlays in:

```
`order` = @fromorder := @fromorder + 1
```

This needs to be changed I guess?

So from this:

```
+-------+-----------+
|   id  |   order   |
+-------+-----------+
|   1   |   0       |
|   2   |   1       |
|   3   |   2       |
|   4   |   3       |
|   5   |   4       |
+-------+-----------+
```

I want to get this (for example) with this query:

```
+-------+-----------+
|   id  |   order   |
+-------+-----------+
|   1   |   5       |
|   2   |   6       |
|   3   |   7       |
|   4   |   8       |
|   5   |   9       |
+-------+-----------+
```

It is an easy for loop with incrementation += 1;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this query? Please [edit] your question to include the sample table with the rows you have and the resulting table you want from that.

Comment: The query that you have does not return your expected results: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u1CjtXV6X3umMooYTz3U9k/0

Comment: Will the original orders always be sequential? Or could one be missing?

Comment: @forpas  I edited the post to be correct... Because I don't care about the result... I just need to know how to rewrite the code so it does the same thing but won't throw the warning.

Comment: @Scratte I just need to know how to rewrite the code so it does the same thing but won't throw the warning.

It is an easy for loop with incrementation += 1;

Comment: @digitalniweb what is your current version of MySql?

Comment: @forpas MySQL 8.0.21

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your version of MySQL supports [*window functions*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html) and by using `ROW_NUMBER()` window function you can avoid variables:

```
UPDATE forms f
CROSS JOIN (SELECT `order` FROM forms WHERE id = 5) c
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY `order`) rn
  FROM forms
  WHERE `order` > -1 and `order` <= 4 
) t ON t.id = f.id
SET f.`order` = c.`order` + t.rn;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=42dd6d1c130c1c37c3f13ef70ba4d3ae).

Comment: Wow, it works, you're a legend... Thank you