# Question about differences in user variable usage between mysql 5.6 and mysql 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I'm trying to upgrade mysql version from 5.6 to 8.0

Some legacy SQL statements contain user defined variables.

my problem is that the result of below query is diffrent between two versions. (it's summary of problem)

```
SELECT @t 
  FROM ( SELECT @t:=0 ) T
 WHERE @t IS NOT NULL
```

In the case of version 5.6,
0 is displayed on the result table.

But, on version 8.0  
there is no row in the result table.
  
It look like @t is still NULL(@t is not defined) in the WHERE clause.
   
I wonder why @t is not defined and assigned in the sub-query in the FROM clause.  

  

 
Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: Looks like using variables in that way is now deprecated. An [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1397f848d6a6e4256b6e96c86683898b) that shows the warning. Also, not sure which exact version of MySQL that you have, but it is mentioned with the [8.0.13](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-8.0-relnotes-en/news-8-0-13.html#mysqld-8-0-13-feature) changes too, at the 2nd bullet item about user variables.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the derived table is not materialized first and
probably an effect of the optimizer using [derived condition pushdown](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/derived-condition-pushdown-optimization.html). It basically rewrites your query to

```
SELECT @t:=0 WHERE @t IS NOT NULL
```

which more obviously returns no rows (if @t is null to begin with), as the where condition finds no rows, so the setting-part will never be executed.

What can you do?

- You can disable that optimization using [optimizer hints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizer-hints.html), e.g. try

  ```
  SELECT /*+ NO_DERIVED_CONDITION_PUSHDOWN() */ @t  
  FROM ( SELECT @t:=0 ) T
  WHERE @t IS NOT NULL
  ```
- You can disable it altogether using the [`optimizer_switch`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_optimizer_switch) configuration and setting `derived_condition_pushdown=off`. This may be useful if you use this a lot and don't want to adjust every query, but will of course also disable that optimization for queries that might profit from it.
- You can initialize the variable before you run that query, e.g. run `set @t := 0` first. Will not be applicable in every situation though.
- You can force MySQL to materialize the derived table. This should always work, even if the actual optimization that causes the effect isn't the derived condition pushdown. A simple way to materialize it is to add an arbitrary `limit`-clause, e.g.

  ```
  SELECT @t  
  FROM ( SELECT @t:=0 limit 10000000 ) T
  WHERE @t IS NOT NULL
  ```

Generally though, be aware that this use of variables (e.g. setting them inside the query) is [deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/8.0/en/news-8-0-13.html#mysqld-8-0-13-feature) (among other reasons also due to effects like in your problem) and will not work anymore in some future version of MySQL. You can usually rewrite those queries using either window functions or recursive ctes, see e.g. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67256687) for an example.

Comment: your answer is exactly right. derived_condition_pushdown optimizer was included from 8.0.22 and I tested on the 8.0.23. thank you for your help!